# Predictable ID's to non-predictable short strings in PHP

Tags: php, decode, encode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Short 'encryption/hash' in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416128/short-encryption-hash-in-php)

Right,

I need to make an ID's e.g; 100000001, 100000002, 100000003 into less predictable strings using PHP such as PDKJ23HB43

- It needs to be alphanumerical.
- (If Possible) It needs to be 5-15 characters in length.
- It needs to be reversible.
- It needs to be unique.
- It doesn't need to be secure [I'm not using it to 'encrypt' anything]
- (If Possible) It can't require a database to record the mappings.
- Is what I'm trying to do at all possible?

I'm thinking it's going to be similar to how URL's get turned into TinyURL's, but that's only a vague guess.

I've tried a few different options such as base64 but the outputs are far too long (I know the reasons why, I just can't find a better solution as this is the first time I've ever needed to do something like this.

Thanks for the help guys, any is greatly appreciated. Sorry if I'm asking very directly, but it's the only way I can get my goal across.

Comment: TinyURLs are randomly generated, then the tiny url and original URL are stored in a db.  It's not a "hash" of the URL.

Comment: So from 100000001 to PDKJ23HB43 (encoded, if you like) then from PDKJ23HB43 back to 100000001 (It's original value)

Comment: That makes sense Rocket - Is what I'm trying to achieve at all possible without using a database for mapping?

Comment: The way SO handled this makes me a little sad. OP wasn't clear about his real need, and he shouldn't have asked again the same question. But the first one should have received more constructive comments in order to finally determine what was the real need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this :

```
echo base_convert(time(), 10, 34).base_convert(rand(), 10, 34);
```

If you want predictable (non secure) id, store just a count somewhere and use

```
echo base_convert(mycount, 10, 34);
```

Answer (score 3):

As you need this to be reversible I'd recommend using [mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php). This will come with an overhead cost though.

If you don't want predictable ID's then why don't you change your system to generate random ID's utilising [`uniqid()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)?

Comment: Thanks Rawkode, this is really helpful. The reason I'm trying to do it this way is because the 'predictable' values are already existent and can't be changed